# PHP inserting NULL into MySQL database when variables store real values

Tags: php, mysql, null

I am using the code below to insert the values from the form into the MySQL database, however after the code executes the MySQL tables displays NULL, NULL instead of the actual value.

I have checked to see whether the values have been correctly obtained from the GET function, and there is no problem in that either

```
<?php
    $vac_name=$_GET['vac_name'];
    $vac_comment=$_GET['vac_comment'];
    echo $vac_name;
    echo $vac_comment;
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
    if($con==true){
        echo "Connected to the database";
     if(isset($_GET['vac_name'], $_GET['vac_comment'])){

        mysql_select_db("attendance_db",$con);
        $query = "insert into vacationtype values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),vac_name,vac_comment)";
        $result=mysql_query($query,$con);
        //$row=mysql_num_rows($result);
    //  if($row>0){
        if($result==true){  
            echo "Successfully saved your message <br> We shall be in contact with you shortly";
        }else{
            echo mysql_error();
            echo "Sorry the message was not saved <br> Please try again. Thank You";
        }   }
        mysql_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Cannot connect to the database";
    }
?>
```

Comment: That's not how [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) works - you're not actually providing the column values. Additionally, please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your query like this

```
insert into vacationtype values('LAST_INSERT_ID()','vac_name','vac_comment')
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `$query="insert into vacationtype values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'". $_GET['vac_name'] ."','". $_GET['vac_comment'] ."')"` ? You have to insert the contents of $_GET.